# Sending non reply messages automatically

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to develop a Bot to automatically send messages to a conversation (conversation at some point will be a slack channel or skype group chat) and I'm using the emulator to test my Bot.

I am planning on using a background thread to execute some things and push the result as a message to that conversation.

To send a non reply message, I need to set certain information in the message such as Recipient, From, and Conversation properties.

I can get a ConversationReference when a member is added that is not the bot. When a member is removed the ConversationReference associated the user can be removed.

I believe that all those references will have to be saved as states somehow...

My question is, is there a better way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you already know that to automatically send message to user, you may [Send proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages). It is suitable for the scenario like setting time to reminder or communicating to user when bot receives a notification from an external system.

There are two types of proactive message: ad hoc proactive message which interjects messages into conversation without regarding the current state of conversation; dialog-based proactive message on the contrary, the current state must be identified before this message is interjected.

> I believe that all those references will have to be saved as states somehow...

Yes you're right, to send proactive message, we need to specify the conversation ID, which is extracted from user's message. And if we don't specify this ID, we need to generate a new ID in our code so that the message will be delivered to the user in a new conversation window.  For saving user state part, you may refer to [Manage state data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state).

> My question is, is there a better way to achieve this?

I'm not sure if there is any better way, but your thoughts is definitely the suggested approach of official documents. And here is the official [botFramework-proactiveMessages sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages).

Comment: Thank you grace. This is what I thought. You just confirmed my assumptions